# Should [qualtrics] (SaaS) be a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed the [qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qualtrics) tag and after looking at the site, http://www.qualtrics.com/, it seems to be a SaaS.  Is that an appropriate tag for SO?

Comment: If the SaaS happens to be a programming tool, then I would say **Yes**, it is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. I don't know what this Qualtrics thing is all about though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Qualtrics is an online survey collection tool. They have both [an API](https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php) and various features for the [automated uploading of marked-up surveys](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/advanced-options-drop-down/import-and-export-surveys/), which can be generated programmatically.

As a comparison, Survey Monkey and Lime Survey are similar tools with APIs that currently have 70+ questions in [surveymonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surveymonkey) and 50+ questions [limesurvey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/limesurvey), respectively.

Definitely seems on-topic to me.